# n-gram language model

Tags: probability, distributions, natural-language, language-models

At the end of the introduction of [A Neural Probabilistic Language Model (Bengio et al. 2003)](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/BengioDVJ03.pdf), the following example is given:

> Having seen the sentence `The cat is walking in the bedroom` in the
>   training corpus should help us generalize to make the sentence `A dog was running in a room` almost as likely.

I get the general spirit, but they provide this example right after explaining that a n-gram language model gives the probability of occurrence of a **word** given some other previous (context) words: $P[w_{t}\mid (w_{t-n+1},...,w_{t-1})]$. So switching to **sentence** probability without transition is a bit confusing.

What do they mean by "making a sentence likely" since the models work at the word level?

PS: I can understand that if we see `The cat is walking in the bedroom` in the training corpus, we can estimate $p_{0}=P[bedroom\mid (cat,walking)]$. It is clear that taking word similarity into account, when generalizing we would want $P[bedroom\mid (dog,running)]$ to be roughly equal to $p_{0}$ (since dog and cat, walking and running, are similar). But this has still to do with word probabilities. And also, what doesn't work here is that in `A dog was running in a room`, $bedroom$ does not occur, so we only deal with $P[room\mid(dog,running)]$.

Answer (score 1):

Language models are often used to compute the probability of a sentence. This is done by using the chain rule.

For example if we want to estimate the probability of observing the sentence $w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4$ we can factorize it like so...

$P(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4) = P(w_4|w_3, w_2, w_1) P(w_3|w_2, w_1) P(w_2| w_1) P(w_1) $

Each of those terms is something that can be straightforwardly computed by the language model.

Comment: @ Aaron - Would you pls share some details about the usefulness of calculating probability of a sentence. I too, like Antoine, could not get my head around it - the need for conditional probability of a word seems natural but not sure about the joint probability of a sentence.

Comment: Let's say you are working on speech recognition and your system can't tell if someone said "wreck a nice beach" or if they said "recognize speech". By running the language model on each utterance you could pick which word sequence is the most likely.